# Ruby rails - parse xml list of entries without knowing the the length

Tags: ruby, xml, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using XmlSimple, the problem I am having is in parsing a list of entries, determine number of entries with similar xml tag.

```
<ItemList>
   <Item>
      <ItemId>123</ItemId>
      <ItemName>abc</ItemName>
      <ItemType>xyz</ItemType>
      <Status>ok</Status>
   </Item>
</ItemList>
```

Above gets parsed as this -

```
"ItemList"=> { 
    "Item"=>{ "ItemId"=>"123", 
              "ItemName"=>"abc", 
              "ItemType"=>"xyz", 
              "Status"=>"ok"
             }
},
```

And I access it as - `['ItemList']['Item']['ItemId']`, Without any Index number anywhere.

But if ItemList has more then 1 entries then it messes up my application.

```
<ItemList>
   <Item>
      <ItemId>123</ItemId>
      <ItemName>abc</ItemName>
      <ItemType>xyz</ItemType>
      <Status>bad</Status>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <ItemId>456</ItemId>
      <ItemName>fgh</ItemName>
      <ItemType>nbv</ItemType>
      <Status>bad</Status>
   </Item>
</ItemList>
```

Above gets parsed as this -

```
"ItemList"=> { 
    "Item"=>{ "ItemId"=>"123", 
              "ItemName"=>"abc", 
              "ItemType"=>"xyz", 
              "Status"=>"bad"
             },
    "Item"=>{ "ItemId"=>"456", 
              "ItemName"=>"fgh", 
              "ItemType"=>"nbv", 
              "Status"=>"bad"
             }
},
```

I can access it as - `['ItemList']['Item'][0]['ItemId']` and `['ItemList']['Item'][1]['ItemId']`. With providing an Index number manually. 
But since I don't know how many items are there in the list I cannot provide index number in the actual app, the xml might have No entry or might have hundreds of them. 
Thought of using Nokogiri, but it has the same parsing behavior. 
How do I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample processing of your data using `xml-simple` gem

```
1.9.2p290 :013 > items = "<ItemList> <Item> <ItemId>123</ItemId> <ItemName>abc</ItemName> <ItemType>xyz</ItemType> <Status>bad</Status> </Item> <Item> <ItemId>456</ItemId> <ItemName>fgh</ItemName> <ItemType>nbv</ItemType> <Status>bad</Status> </Item> </ItemList>"
     => "<ItemList> <Item> <ItemId>123</ItemId> <ItemName>abc</ItemName> <ItemType>xyz</ItemType> <Status>bad</Status> </Item> <Item> <ItemId>456</ItemId> <ItemName>fgh</ItemName> <ItemType>nbv</ItemType> <Status>bad</Status> </Item> </ItemList>" 

1.9.2p290 :014 > parsed_items = XmlSimple.xml_in(items, { 'KeyAttr' => 'name' })
     => {"Item"=>[{"ItemId"=>["123"], "ItemName"=>["abc"], "ItemType"=>["xyz"], "Status"=>["bad"]}, {"ItemId"=>["456"], "ItemName"=>["fgh"], "ItemType"=>["nbv"], "Status"=>["bad"]}]} 

1.9.2p290 :015 > parsed_items.class
     => Hash 

1.9.2p290 :016 > parsed_items["Item"].class
     => Array 

1.9.2p290 :017 > parsed_items["Item"].length
     => 2
```

So your `Item` will be an array and you can apply `length` method on it. With my example above you can always do `parsed_items["Item"].length`

Comment: thanks Pravin, I will try this. The other thing I should have mentioned is there are more tags other than ItemList in the xml I am parsing, again length of those other tags can also vary. That will cause an issue.

Comment: You can inspect keys in the main resultant hash by e.g.`parsed_items.keys` and check class for each key you want to process and apply methods accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If 'result' is what you get from parsing your XML doc, then you could test

```
result['ItemList']['Item']
```

to check whether it is an array (or enumerable). If it is, then there's more than 1 item, and you'll have to enumerate over the items.

Alternatively, you could do this (assuming ruby 1.9):

```
[*result['ItemList']['Item']].each do |item|
   ...
end
```

The splat operator is [cool](http://kconrails.com/2010/12/22/rubys-splat-operator/) and when used like this lets you transparently handle a value that could be nil, a scalar, or a collection.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ruby 1.8+, I use REXML which makes this easy. See the Accessing Elements section: http://www.germane-software.com/software/rexml/docs/tutorial.html

Comment: Personally, for performance reasons, I'd go for libxml-ruby or nokogiri over REXML.